# Watchtower when someone uses a Masquerade

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue, dominion-prosperity

As a reaction card, Watchtower can be revealed whenever you gain a card.

[image: Watchtower card]

Does this apply to the card you receive from other players during a Masquerade?

[image: Masquerade card]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  A passed card is not considered a gained card.

**From the [Intrigue rulebook](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_306_gameRules.pdf):**

> “Pass” – when a player passes a card to another player, he places that card face down on the table between himself and the other player. The receiving player then takes the card from the table and puts it in his hand. A passed card is not revealed to the other players. A passed card is not considered to be trashed or discarded by the player passing it and it is not considered to be gained by the player receiving it.

Comment: I looked in the rulebook, but apparently not at the right section.  Whoops.

Answer (score -3):

The only way you gain a card is if the card specifically says the word "gain" or when you spend money to buy it off of a supply pile. Anything else that results in you having a new card in your deck is not a "gain".

Edit: Total brain fart, thanks commenters!

Comment: This is not true.  Many other cards let you "gain" a card without buying it (like Workshop or Mine), but they always use the word "gain" in the card text.  Masquerade specifically does not use the word "gain", which is why Watchtower doesn't work against it.

Comment: That would be wrong.  I can think of more than a dozen cards that specify you gain cards: Feast, Mine, Remodel, Thief, Witch, Workshop, Baron, Bureaucrat, Ironworks, Saboteur, Swindler, Torturer, Trading Post, Upgrade... and that's just from Base and Intrigue!

Comment: On the plus side, the rare "Peer Pressure" badge is now yours to claim!